# Synax Error When Trying To Create SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, database-design

I am receiving this error when trying to create my database Failure 1 (near "CREATE_TABLE": syntax error) on 0x367f80 when preparing 'CREATE_TABLE cattletypes (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , cattle_type TEXT);'.

The code I use is

```
    db.execSQL("CREATE_TABLE " + CattleType.CATTLETYPE_TABLE_NAME + " ("
        + CattleType._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
        + CattleType.CATTLE_TYPE_NAME + " TEXT"
        + ");");
```

I've been reading it and rereading it and can't for the life of me figure out where my error is -
my class code is

```
        public static final class CattleType implements BaseColumns{
        private CattleType() {}
        public static final String CATTLETYPE_TABLE_NAME = "cattletypes";
        public static final String CATTLE_TYPE_NAME = "cattle_type";
        public static final String DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER = "cattle_type ASC";
        }
```

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Haven't used SQLLite but should there be an underscore between CREATE and TABLE? There isn't in any other SQL variant I've used.

Comment: Thank you that's what comes from not taking a break...now for the rest of the issues..thanks again

Comment: No problem. As it was the answer and I posted the comment a while before the others who posted the same thing as answers, I'll post it as an answer myself.

Comment: Whoever downvoted the question - I don't think that's fair. We all have days when we miss something that's staring us in the face - this question was asked clearly and all the information needed to answer it was given. You can't ask for more than that on SO in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

There is a '_' between CREATE and TABLE. Remove that and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `_` between `CREATE` and `TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, an extraneous underscore has found its way between `CREATE` and `TABLE`.